# hover the entire row of the div display:table properties

Tags: html, css, hover

I would like to hover the entire row that contain div cell.

The main div has display:table properties.

Im trying css3 pseudo classes nth child but not working properly.

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks.

```css
div.table{
 margin:auto;
    display:table;
    width:800px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
div.row
{
    display:table-row;
}

div.cell
{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
div.cell:nth-child(8){
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
div.cell:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
}
div.cell:hover ~ div:nth-child(1n)
{
    background-color: #B38E8E;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">NAME</div>
        <div class="cell">GENDER</div>
        <div class="cell">STATUS</div>
        <div class="cell">CITIZENSHIP</div>
        <div class="cell">TIN</div>
        <div class="cell">SSS</div>
        <div class="cell">PHIL. HEALTH</div>
        <div class="cell">ACTION</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ock7vhL0/ like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ock7vhL0/)**

Use this code

```
div.row:hover
{
    background-color: #B38E8E;
}
```

instead of

```
div.cell:hover ~ div:nth-child(1n)
{
    background-color: #B38E8E;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the thing you need. Hover on row not on cell.

```css
div.table{
 margin:auto;
    display:table;
    width:800px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
div.row
{
    display:table-row;
}

div.cell
{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
div.cell:nth-child(8){
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
div.cell:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
}
div.row:hover 
{
    background-color: #B38E8E;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">NAME</div>
        <div class="cell">GENDER</div>
        <div class="cell">STATUS</div>
        <div class="cell">CITIZENSHIP</div>
        <div class="cell">TIN</div>
        <div class="cell">SSS</div>
        <div class="cell">PHIL. HEALTH</div>
        <div class="cell">ACTION</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 1 Data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
        <div class="cell">ROW 2 Data</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below styles in your stylesheet and try.

```
.row:hover{
    background-color: #B38E8E;
}
```